# Is there a way to use columns in a dataframe to index a matrix to produce another column via mutation function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new to R and so forgive my basic knowledge but this is what I have tried:

```r
df1 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = matrix_1[col_1,col_2])
```

`matrix_1` is the matrix I have created

`col_1` and `col_2` are variables from `df2`

not sure if i am thinking about this in the wrong way

Comment: just to add the values in col_1 and col_2 match the matrix column and row names

Comment: df2, matrix, col_1 and col_2 are all missing from the question.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on asking questions.  In particular all inputs must be provided using dput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```r
df2 %>%
  mutate(new_col = matrix_1[cbind(col_1, col_2)])
```

`[.matrix` (and `[.data.frame`) allows you to index by a set of row/column indices by using a matrix. Namely, from [`?[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

```
i, j, ...: indices specifying elements to extract or replace.  Indices
          ...

          When indexing arrays by '[' a single argument 'i' can be a
          matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of 'x';
          the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to
          the sets of indices in each row of 'i'.
```

Here's a reprex:

```r
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3), col2 = c(2, 4))
df
#   col1 col2
# 1    1    2
# 2    3    4

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(newcol = m[cbind(col1, col2)])
#   col1 col2 newcol
# 1    1    2      4
# 2    3    4     12
```

Comment: thank you, this worked! Would you be able to explain more simply what the cbind is doing in this argument?

Comment: `cbind(.)` is building a `matrix`. It takes the two columns and ... turns them into two columns (of a matrix).